# Not able to get the aggregate result in mongo embedded document by querying

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

Issue in querying the embedded document in mongo db. I am trying to get the `conversationId` for the users but it returning null.

Sample document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5787391f191fda3a4430c749"),
"conversationId" : "fWFGIr0xAbQytmVcQIPV",
"user" : [{_id : "800", "name" : "Tim"},{_id : "500", "name" : "Kingsley"},
{_id : "400", "name" : "Roger"}],
"type" : "PRIVATE"
}
```

Query:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("type").is("PRIVATE")),
            group("conversationId").push("user.id").as("users"),
            match(Criteria.where("users").all(Arrays.asList('800','400','500')))
            );
    AggregationResults<Rooms> groupResults = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, ROOMS, Rooms.class);
      List<Rooms> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
      result.get(0).getId() // returns null
```

The `result.get(0).getId()` is returning null, as per my query I am expecting the conversation Id that is present for the users.

Comment: What sort of result are you expecting?

Comment: @chridam: I am expecting the conversationId , but I am getting null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, why you are grouping on conversationId and then creating a set with user's id who took part in that conversation.

If your desired result is to find a conversation in which the users '800', '400' and '500', then you can straight away use find query with $all.

Mongo Query will look like this:

```
db.test.find({"user._id":{"$all":["800","500","400"]}})
```

Comment: Yeah my desired result is like that only. But, its not finding the desired conversation Id

Comment: @Karthik: You tried with the above query? can you paste that java code?

Comment: Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("type").is("PRIVATE")),
                group("conversationId").push("user._id").as("users"),
                match(Criteria.where("users").all(userProfileIds))

Comment: @Karthik You are once again doing the grouping. As per your statement, you don't need to aggregate too. So can you just try 'find' query for the mongo query given above?

Comment: Its working , I have some other issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395261/getting-com-mongodb-mongoexceptionduplicatekey-in-mongodb-with-java-using-upser