# Getting com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey in mongodb with java using upsert

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am not able to update the existing record with mongo db upsert using java.
I wrote a query to find the record using id but when trying to update its throwing com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey exception.

Sample data:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5788bef4191fda5c9077af78"),
    "type" : "PRIVATE",
    "users" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "800",
                    "Name" : "Jack"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "530a7998-ba3f-4366-8d21-bb1ca688cfdb",
                    "Name" : "Ashley"
            }
    ]}
```

Java query

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is("5788bef4191fda5c9077af78"));
    Update args = new Update();
    args.addToSet("users", users);// users is a List<User>users.
    args.addToSet("type", "GROUP");
    mongoOps.upsert(query, args, Rooms.class, ROOMS);//mongoOps is MongoOperations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to pass only list to addToset . And set to update a string field.

Below code worked and document got updated.

```
Update args = new Update(); args.addToSet("users", new BasicDBObject("$each", users)); args.set("type", "GROUP"); mongoOps.upsert(query, args, Rooms.class, ROOMS);
```

Comment: If the problem is resolved, please mark it "solved" as well.